# Why when i debug my value option tag html is undefined?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried debugging the following error for several hours with no solution JS is still undefined but id parameter in controller has a value. Please help. I need it.

**This html code when i debug, the value is undefined, why the value is undefined?**

```
<select id="cmbTipe" class="form-control">
                <option value="-1">Select Jenis</option>
                <option value="undefined">undefined</option>
                <option value="undefined">undefined</option>
            </select>
```

**My Controller**

```
namespace PerhitunganKeuntunganParkir.Controllers{

public class ParkirController : Controller
{
    private readonly JenisKendaraanRepository _jeniskendaraanRepository = null;
    private readonly TipeKendaraanRepository _tipekendaraanRepository = null;
    private readonly ParkirContext _context = null;

    //Dependency Injection
    public ParkirController(JenisKendaraanRepository jenisKendaraanRepository, TipeKendaraanRepository tipeKendaraanRepository, ParkirContext context)
    {
        _jeniskendaraanRepository = jenisKendaraanRepository;
        _tipekendaraanRepository = tipeKendaraanRepository;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<ViewResult> GetAllJenis()
    {
        ViewBag.Jenis = await _jeniskendaraanRepository.GetJenisKendaraan();

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult LoadTipeC(int jenisId)
    {
        
        return Json(_context.TipeKendaraan.Where(s=>s.JenisKendaraanId ==
            jenisId).Select(s=> new TipeKendaraanModel{
                Id = s.Id,
                Tipe=s.Tipe

        }).ToList());
    }
```

**My View**

In HTML my cascading dropdown the value is undefined, why does this happen? The JavaScript is working but the value is undefined in HTML

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Input Form";

@model JenisKendaraanModel

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" asp-action="GetAllJenis" asp-controller="Parkir">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Jenis"></label>
            <select id="cmbJenis" class="form-control">
                <option value="-1">Select Jenis</option>
                @foreach (var jenis in ViewBag.Jenis)
                {
                    <option value="@jenis.Id">@jenis.Jenis</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Jenis" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="cmbTipe" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>


        <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cmbJenis').on('change', function () {
                var jenisId = $('#cmbJenis option:selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { jenisId: jenisId },
                    url: '@Url.Action("LoadTipeC","Parkir")',
                    success: function (result) {
                        //var tipe = JSON.parse(result);
                        var s = '<option value="-1">Select tipe</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            s += '<option value="' + result[i].Id + '">' + result[i].Tipe + '</option>';
                        }
                        $('#cmbTipe').html(s);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "javascript is undefined"?

Comment: in html the value cascading dropdown my Id and Tipe is undefined

Comment: When you debug, what is the exact data in `result`?  Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the AJAX request/response, to debug the client-side code, even just log the value to the console.

Comment: I suggest getting the data in `LoadTipeC` into a variable and checking that variable before sending it using `Json()` and make sure it has the data you expect. Also, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))` to get a readable representation of what's in `result` to make sure it has what you think it should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my test, I found that your problem may lie in your Js.

Try to change your code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
  s += '<option value="' + result[i].Id + '">' + result[i].Tipe + '</option>';
}
```

To

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
  s += '<option value="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].tipe + '</option>';
}
```

`id` and `tipe` the first letter should be lowercase.